# AWS-S3: How do multipart upload increases throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multi-upload

If I am having a file of 1GB and have upload speed of 1MBps. So if I will upload whole file or will upload it in parts, the total uploading speed would not increase since I am having an upper bound on the upload speed. Am I right or there is some other scenario?

Comment: If you are fully utilizing the bandwidth, then it will not improve transfer speed.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. In your scenario there is little to gain from parallel multipart uploads.

The recommendation to use parallel multipart uploads is when you have more bandwidth available on your end than will be used per S3 connection.